# Problem while Creating Dynamic ModalPopup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajax

i want to create a modalpopup dynamically but i come across a problem.I pasted my sub here and i dont know what to do for that problem.When i want to show modalpopup,it says 
"Control 'mdldelete2' of type 'ModalPopupExtender' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." How can i solve this?

```
Public Sub Raise_Alarm(ByRef p_Page As Page, 
                       ByRef p_AssignedButton As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button,
                       ByVal p_Message As String)

    Dim mdldelete2 As Global.AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender = 
                        p_Page.Page.FindControl("mdldelete2")

    If mdldelete2 Is Nothing Then
        mdldelete2 = New Global.AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender
    End If

    With mdldelete2

        .TargetControlID = p_AssignedButton.ID
        .PopupControlID = "pnlDelete"
        .ID = "mdldelete2"
        .BackgroundCssClass = "modalBackground"
        .OkControlID = "btnDeleteOk"
        .CancelControlID = "btnDeleteCancel"
    End With

    p_Page.Controls.Add(mdldelete2)

    Dim mylabel As Label
    mylabel = p_Page.FindControl("lblStatus")

    mylabel.Text = p_Message
    mdldelete2.Show()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, you should be adding the `mdldelete2` control to the `Controls` collection of the Form control, rather than the Page directly - that might help.

I often find it's easier to add a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) control to the page for this sort of thing - it doesn't add anything directly to the page, but gives you a named container to find and add controls to.

Also, just a point - if you did find an instance of the control with the Page.FindControl method, then you don't need to add it to a form collection again, as it's already in there.

Comment: Zhaph,
 Thanks for ur help.First of all i wanna tell that why i want to write that.I want to fire modalpopup in my pages after executing some server code.Forexample in delete button click event i want to tell to user Delete is completed or Delete couldnt be completed.I can do this by adding modalpopup every page but i want to write a sub in a class and call it in my pages.I dont want to drag & drop modalpopup control to my every page.By the way after put it in place holder,i dont come across error but i dont see modalpopup although i execute Mdlpopup.Show.Do u have any idea why?

Comment: Ok,i solved.Adding referance of page causes problem.Finding placeholder in page and then adding to placeholder.controls solves this problem.Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a ScriptManager control to the aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```